# XAMPP / Apache not loading new resources?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm using newly installed XAMPP with Apache and MySQL, first hours was fine it loading resources normally. But, after a half day it not loaded newly added content from style.css and script.js(I just added standard properties like a height, width, color). I tried restart services or reinstall also run from administrator but nothing changed.

- I'm using `index.php` and if I edit anything or add styles in `index.php` with `<style></style>` tag it works normally, so there is no problem about compiling CSS or JavaScript.
- My code have no problem I have tried change styles to work with id, class or tag. But, problem is server not loading newly added resources.
- If needed I can also upload logs

Comment: This is likely simply a problem with your _browser_ cache, so clear that; or use ctrl + r/ctrl + f5 on Windows, cmd + shift + r on a Mac.

Comment: If you will be making frequent changes to this after it goes "live", where you can't ask your site visitors to clear their caches all the time - then go read up on the keyword "cache buster."

Comment: To reload your page without cache use CTRL + F5 (or with firefox F12 -> network -> disable cache)

Comment: Thanks, 

Deleting browser cache worked, I think that don't work because I deleted a week ago.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your browser is caching the website and loading the cached version.

There are a few ways to bypass caching that work in most browsers, such as:

- Viewing the site from incognito mode
- Hard refreshing the site: CTRL + F5 on Chrome, Command + Option + R on Safari
- Disabling the cache through your browsers developer tools: on Chrome, F12 -> Network -> Disable cache

Caching allows your site to load faster, but might display old content in certain situations.